# Disable hive in spark context (OrcFileFormat not a subtype)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am getting the following exception in my spark application, and I am only using SparkSQL to run filters in my dataframe. So I would like to disable the hive support.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcFileFormat not a subtype
```

Can you do this? I am using the following versions when it comes to Scala and Spark.

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>2.2.1</spark.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.major.version>2.11</scala.major.version>
</properties>
```

I tried to set the property `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` to `in-memory`, but this did not help either. This is how I am currently setting my spark session and passing the configuration.

```
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","in-memory")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.orc.enabled","false")

// Configure generic spark application
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .config(sparkConf)
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: any update on this, facing same issue.